# BLE advertising and scanning in background (long-running)

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-background

Is there a way to scan for BLE devices and advertise data at the same time in background (even when application is removed from application tray)?

So far the application can scan and advertise data while it is minimized or while the screen is turned off. But as soon as I remove it from the application tray, it kills the service running it without a call to `onDestroy` from `Services`. The service also runs on a separate thread.

The code for my Service is based off on first example given at [Android Dev Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services). And this Service initiates bleScan and bleAdvertise.

I am sorry if this question doesn't make sense. It is the first Android app I am building on Android studio.

Comment: See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services (with `<service android:foregroundServiceType="connectedDevice"`) on Android 10+)

Comment: @ephemient with this doesn't the user have to run the app every-time to initiate the process? I want this process to keep running in the background even when device restarts.

Comment: Register a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver) for [BOOT_COMPLETED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) in your manifest (along with appropriate permissions as documented) to autostart. Note that many phone vendors require other explicit user action for this to work. https://dontkillmyapp.com